# How can I modify values of array objects comparing it at once on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am printing on my map locations provide me by API. In some cases locations return the same lat and lng , if for example I get 5 locations and 3 locations have the same locations i only see 3 ubications, because 3 locations is in the same point.

My quickly solution i think is : 
loop my object array and add 0.00001 or 0.0002 to look all locations on my map .

```
let points=
[{
        "id": 1,
        "description": "LOC 1",
        "latitude": 37.3676908,
        "longitude": -6.0432685
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "LOC 2",
        "latitude": 37.3676908,
        "longitude": -6.0432685
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "LOC 3",
        "latitude": 37.3676908,
        "longitude": -6.0432685
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "description": "LOC 4",
        "latitude": 37.363128,
        "longitude": -6.0455416
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "description": "LOC 5",
        "latitude": 37.369319,
        "longitude": -6.0421527
    }
]
```

I want to get the next :

```
let points=
[{
        "id": 1,
        "description": "LOC 1",
        "latitude": 37.3676908,
        "longitude": -6.0432685
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "LOC 2",
        "latitude": 37.3676909,
        "longitude": -6.0432686
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "LOC 3",
        "latitude": 37.3676910,
        "longitude": -6.0432687
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "description": "LOC 4",
        "latitude": 37.363128,
        "longitude": -6.0455416
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "description": "LOC 5",
        "latitude": 37.369319,
        "longitude": -6.0421527
    }
]
```

I've tried to achieve that with .sort and .filter but I dont find nice solution to it.

Could someone help me . Thank  you in advance

Comment: do you want new objects with adjusted values, or do you like to sort? what has sort to do with it? why not filter duplicates?

Comment: Or use [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `map` if you want to do an operation to every object in an array.

`points.map(x => x + Math.random()/1000)` would add a random tiny number.

But you can do whatever function you want on x after the `x =>` part.  Maybe something like

`points.map(myfunc)` and you can define myfunc as add .0001 or add .0002 based on some condition.

Comment: `x => myfunc(x)` is redundant. If you already have a function `myfunc` that takes an element from the array, then you can just pass it directly `points.map(myfunc)`